# How to Filter React Bootstrap Cards using onClick()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm just starting out with React and I am trying to build a basic site that displays cards. When a button is pressed, I'd only like cards with a matching subject/description to be shown. I'm using React Bootstrap's [Card-Columns](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/).

Here's an example of what each card looks like:

```
<Card>
  <Card.Img variant="top" src="./image" />
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>Title</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
      Text here.
    </Card.Text>
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
```

I have a hunch that I should be creating a state for the cards called subject and have some kind of filter function, but I'm a bit unsure of how to implement that.

I am hoping someone can link some resources or give some tips! Thanks!

Comment: Post your state and your complete HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented something, related to question. Try this,
I have created an array of numbers, onChange on select I have filtered the card as you mentioned. Used the same `react-bootstrap` library

Here I am filtering the card with matching titles.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";


const titles = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 7, 4, 3, 6, 6, 4, 5];


const App = () => {
  const [selected, updateSelect] = useState(1)

  const onChange = (e) => updateSelect(Number(e.target.value))
  return (
    <Container className="p-3">
        <h1 className="header">Welcome To React-Bootstrap</h1>
        <select onChange={onChange}>
          {[1,2,3,4,5,6].map(num => <option value={num}>{num}</option>)}
        </select>
        {titles.filter(n => n===selected).map(num => (
          <Card>
          {/* <Card.Img variant="top" src="./image" /> */}
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>{num}</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                Text here.
              </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        )

        )}

    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```